# JSON URL data read in Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I am bit new to JSON and Windows 8 phone programming.
I am trying to read the JSON data in windows phone 8 app.
I have tried using Nuget dll but i am not able to add them in my windows 8 phone project.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://10.0.0.205/tzimobileapp/tzimobileservice.svc/getrechargeproducts")); 
}

void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{

        RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result); 
        foreach(var amount in rootObject.Amount) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(amount);
}
```

So i am getting error near JsonConvert. 
Apart from this nuget dll, is microsoft provides other methods to achieve the same?
I dont want to use the third party dll.

My requirement is to read the JSON data sent by client in url form and display in windows phone 8 app. any recommendation would be helpful. thanks.

Comment: "So i am getting error near JsonConvert." - What error? No one can assist you if there is no inclination of whats wrong.

Comment: json convert is not found, i m not able to add the dll from newtons in windows phone 8 app, is there any other dll for windows phone 8

Comment: which dll should i use for windows phone 8?

Comment: You should use the nuget package manager to add the correct dll ; The JSON.NET package should be added. do not add dlls manually.

Comment: hi i tried doing the same from package console manager but its giving me error :PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.8'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.8'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.8'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', 
but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this:
hope working.

```
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<RootObject >));
            RootObject rootObject = (List<RootObject >)serializer.ReadObject(e.result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm looking at the comments, it might be you don't have the latest Nuget Package Manager installed. Which version do you have installed?

Else, I would suggest to try to create a new blank WP projects and install the json.NET package. I've managed to add the package to my WP project, so the json.NET package itself is stable.